# Facing a HttpHostConnectException while using geckodriver

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, webdriver, geckodriver

i just started setting up automation in my office with 
    the help of selenium but strucked at the initial level only. I used a 
    basic code initially just to check the browser is working and processing 
    the code further but got an issue.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class ABC {




public static void main(String[] args) 
{

    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\Users\\12345678\\
    AppData\\Local\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe");

    DesiredCapabilities dc=DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
    FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
    dc.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, profile);
    WebDriver driver =  new FirefoxDriver(dc);
    driver.get("http://www.google.com");
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

}`


    **Below is the error i am facing**
```

`

```
 Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: 
    org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to 
    localhost:44853 
    [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection 
    refused: connect
    Build info: version: '3.3.1', revision: '5234b32', time: '2017-03-10 
    09:04:52 -0800'
    System info: host: 'NODHCMSLTP1115', ip: '10.203.124.34', os.name: 
    'Windows 
    7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_92'
    Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver at 

 org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(Driver
 CommandExecutor.java:91) at 




    org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.
     java:604)at 

  org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver
 .java:244)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>
    (RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>
   (FirefoxDriver.java:218)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>
   (FirefoxDriver.java:125)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>
   (FirefoxDriver.java:150)
    at seleniumProjectauto.Rks_Asu.main(Rks_Asu.java:27)
    Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to 
    localhost:44853 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: 
    Connection refused: connect
    at 
    org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect
    (DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:158)
    at 
    org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect
    (PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:353)
    at 
    org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute
    (MainClientExec.java:380)
    at         
    org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.
    java:236)
    at 

   org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:
    184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
    at 
    org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:
    110)
    at 
   org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttp
    Client
   .java:184)
    at 
    org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttp
    Client.java:71)
    at 
    org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttp
    Client.java:55)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.fallBackExecute
    (ApacheHttpClient.java:142)
    at   
    org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.execute(ApacheHttp
    Client.java:88)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(Protocol
    Handshake.java:296)
    at 
    org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHand
    shake.java:113)
    at 
    org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommand
    Executor.java:141)

at 

org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute
(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
... 7 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
at 
java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl
.java:85)
at 
java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl
.java:350) at 
 java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocket
Impl.java:206)
at 
java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.
java:188)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
at 
org.apache.http.conn.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket
(PlainConnectionSocketFactory.java:74)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect
(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:141)
... 22 more`
```

Comment: Did you try with other websites? Maybe google.com refuses connections. Try with http://localhost

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks fine but a couple of points:

1. To work with Selenium 3.x & Mozila Firefox 52.x you need to download the latest gecko driver from [this location](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) and save it.
2. Instead of "firefox.exe" you need to provide absolute path of the "geckodriver.exe"

Replace:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\Users\\12345678\\
    AppData\\Local\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe");
```

By:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\your_directory\\geckodriver.exe");
```

3. Finally you code will look like:

   ```
   System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\SeleniumUtilities\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");
   DesiredCapabilities dc = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
   FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
   dc.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, profile);
   WebDriver driver =  new FirefoxDriver(dc);
   driver.manage().window().maximize();
   driver.get("http:\\gmail.com");
   ```

This code executes good with me.

Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: Thanks dev but it is still not working and throws this error.          
                                                                                                     xception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Expected browser binary location, but unable to find binary in default location, no 'moz:firefoxOptions.binary' capability provided, and no binary flag set on the command line (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds

Comment: @hemant Check my updated Answer along with the code & let me know if that works.Thanks